# How to get struct layouts from vertex shader input using ID3D12Reflection

Tags: c++, directx, directx12, vertex-shader, code-reflection

I am attempting to write a code generator that builds C++ structs/classes from D3D12 reflection data built using DXC. Given a simple vertex shader signature:

```
struct Light
{
    float3 Color;
    float3 Dir;
};

struct cbPerPass : register(b0)
{
    float4x4 gWorldProjTransform;
    Light gGlobaLight;
};

struct VertexIn
{
    float3 Pos      : POSITION;
    float4 Color    : COLOR;
};

struct VertexOut;  // unimportant for the question

VertexOut VS(VertexIn vin) { // do calculations here }
```

I can retrieve the input parameters via `ID3D12ShaderReflection::GetInputParameterDesc()`, but this only reports the mapping of `VertexIn` members to shader registers and any attached semantics. I can get the layout of `cbPerPass` through `ID3D12ShaderReflection::GetConstantBufferByIndex()` and the layout of `Light` through the `ID3D12ShaderReflectionType` interface.

However, what I would like to retrieve is the layout of the `VertexIn` struct. Is there a way to do this?